# Bind a value to a control's absolute position in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-positioning

Is there a way to bind a value to the absolute position of a control using XAML?

I have a [`Line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line.aspx) element that I would like to be drawn between two [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx)s in my application. I was thinking that binding the starting point of the `Line` to the position of the `Button` would be the easiest way to make this happen, using [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PracticeSample.MyButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" X2="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=ActualWidth}" Y2="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
</Grid>
```

use this MyButton in your pages in place of Button,

Edit:
if you want to draw line between two controls
don't use above code sample but try this directly in your page:

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10">
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Add" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="5"/>
    <Button Name="button" Content="Refresh Control" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50"/>
    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Left),ElementName=button2}" Y1="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Top), ElementName=button2}" X2="{Binding (Canvas.Left), ElementName=button}" Y2="{Binding (Canvas.Top), ElementName=button}"/>
</Canvas>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I ended up doing the drawing in my code-behind file so that I could do some calculations for the positions, rather than just the corner of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Template with Button and Line positioned at right places wherever you like and then use this Template at the place of Button.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify--I cannot use a template because I want to bind both the start and end points. I want the line drawn between two arbitrary elements.